# I want Rich Text Editor and HTML place holder for the some of the description fields in Visualforce page using slds

Tags: visualforce, html5

Find my code below:
I am able to display rich text editor but not html placeholder.

```
                  <div
                   class="slds-form-element__row ma-ltss-font_style slds-p- 
                   top_xxx-small slds-p-left_small ">
                   <div class="slds-size_1-of-5  ">
                     <label class="evv-slds-form-element__label ">Security 
                   Considerations </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 mh-ltss-requiredInput">
                     <div class="mh-ltss-requiredBlock"></div>
                    <apex:inputTextarea richText="true" 
                    value="{!UserStory__c.Security_Considerations__c}" html- 
                     placeholder="Give a brief description of user impact"  
                    style="width: 250Px; height: 150px;"/>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                  &nbsp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its Not possible.

**Reason:**

If you notice what is rendered for tag `<apex:>`, you will find that there are lot of elements like div, span etc. But the most important one is `iframe` inside which we enter the content. Inside iframe you will find another html document in which you will simply have `head` and `body`. You cannot get functional `placeholder` by setting it on any of the elements (you can try it in console directly):

[image]

Comment: Do you think this is not even possible with Javascript.?

Comment: i will check and let you know